# Enter 10 values and summing up all the values in a Java Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am just starting out with arrays and can't figure out why my code is wrong. It should let the user enter 10 values and then display the sum.

Here is my code:

```
//This program let the user enter 10 values and  sums them up 

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter 10 values:");
        double myArray[] = new double[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[i] = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The values are " + myArray[i]);

            for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

                int sum = 0;
                sum += myArray[i];

                System.out.println("The sum of the values is:" + sum);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you for your support

Comment: What is it actually doing? Is it throwing a specific error message? Does it return zero results?

Comment: move `int sum = 0;` outside the `for` loop and before the loop and the final `System.out.println` after the loop

Comment: Also move the inner for loop outside the outer for loop.

Comment: for every iteration of the loop you are declaring a new `int sum` and adding the value of `myArray[i]` to 0, meaning you aren't getting the sum. You need to think about the scope of the variable, and printing the sum after the for loop completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from your loops (they should be one after the other), and how you initialize your variable `sum` (it should be initialized outside the loop).

**Your code should rather be something like this:**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("please enter 10 values:");
double myArray[] = new double[10];
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The values are " + myArray[i]);
}
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    sum += myArray[i];
}
System.out.println("The sum of the values is:" + sum);
```

**Or with only one loop**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("please enter 10 values:");
double myArray[] = new double[10];
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The values are " + myArray[i]);
    sum += myArray[i];
}
System.out.println("The sum of the values is:" + sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct code for your problem:

You have enclosed summing up values inside the

> input for loop

.
You should also define `int sum=0;` separately outside the second for loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("please enter 10 values:");
            double myArray[] = new double[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {//open here
                myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("The values are " + myArray[i]);
            }//close here. you will input values inside this loop


                int sum = 0;//if you have to initialize sum only once, if you put it inside for loop sum wil be zero after every iteration in the loop
                for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {//here you add up all values


                    sum += myArray[i];

                    System.out.println("The sum of the values is:" + sum);

                }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, you are **doing loops inside other loops**.
Every thing you do in a loop is **repeated as many times as the loops number**.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter 10 values:");
        double myArray[] = new double[10];

        // Read the value from the user
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        // display values
        System.out.println("The values are ");
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
             System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        }

        // Do sum
        // Sum start at 0 outside the loop and then we are going to add every number
        int sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                sum += myArray[i];   
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the values is:" + sum);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i want to say that you init 10 double array but you give the value with int,it can happen error and the blew the sum is also int.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it like this.
Here you have to provide exactly 10 numbers to get the sum.

```
    System.out.println("please enter 10 values:");
    double myArray[] = new double[10];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(input.hasNextInt()){
            myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The values are " + myArray[i]);
            sum += myArray[i];
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not a value.");
            i--;
        }
        input = null;
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of the values is:" + sum);
```